# Write exception message in table

Tags: postgresql, exception, transactions

I have the following function, which is called by an Web API to import some uploaded data. There is also an `upload_log` Table which holds the state of the upload and is pollable by the API.

My Question is specific to Postgresql transaction management: I know, that all between the `BEGIN...END` Block is a transaction in PG and that it is getting rolled back automatically as soon as one statement fails.

Therefore the exception shouldn't never get written to the upload_log Table, should it?

Nevertheless, I get error messages in my upload_log and I am asking myself why this happens.

- Is it because of the nested function call `PERFORM...`?
- Is it because of the `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS...` that enables to write something in a table afterwards?
- Do I have to explicitely call `ROLLBACK` in the EXCEPTION Block?
- Do I have to write my upload_log with DBLink as an "Autonomous Transaction"

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION finalize_upload(sync_id in varchar)
    RETURNS void AS $$
    DECLARE
       vCount numeric;
       err1 text;
       err2 text;
       err3 text;
    BEGIN
       -- Mark as Upload in Progress
       update upload_log
       set
          sync_status='1'
       where
          upload_log.gto_sync_id=finalize_upload.sync_id;

       begin
          vCount := 1;

          -- do some heavy stuff
          -- move data from import tables into production
          perform finalize_upload_specific(finalize_upload.sync_id);

       exception when others then
          GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS err1 = MESSAGE_TEXT,
                            err2 = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
                            err3 = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT;

          -- Mark Upload as failed
          update upload_log
          set
             END_DATE=current_timestamp,
             sync_status='-1',
             err_hint=err1||' '||err2||' '||err3
          where
             upload_log.sync_id=finalize_upload.sync_id;
       end
       ;
    END
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything between the `BEGIN` and the associated `EXCEPTION` in a PL/pgSQL block will be executed in a subtransaction.

If any of the handled exceptions is thrown, the subtransaction is rolled back, but the enclosing transaction continues. The `UPDATE` in the exception handler will be committed because it is already outside the subtransaction that gets rolled back.

To illustrate it with pseude-code and SQL savepoints:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE upload_log SET sync_status='1' ...;
SAVEPOINT a;
SELECT finalize_upload_specific($1);
-- if an exception was thrown:
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT a;
RELEASE SAVEPOINT a;
UPDATE upload_log SET sync_status='-1' ...;
COMMIT;
-- else
ROLLBACK;
```